# Print a table format of a numpy matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, tabular

in one of my course projects I have written the simplex algorithm and recorded the output in a NumPy matrix as the following

```
table =
[[-1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  2.13333333e+00 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e-01 6.66666667e-02  3.86666667e+00  6.00000000e+00  4.50000000e+00 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  2.42766667e+03]
 [ 3.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  4.00000000e+02]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00 -8.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00  8.00000000e+00 -3.00000000e+00 -3.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  8.00000000e+01]
 [ 5.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -5.33333333e-01 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -6.66666667e-02  5.33333333e-01 -2.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e-01 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.33333333e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  4.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 -4.00000000e+00  2.00000000e+00  2.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.60000000e+02]
 [ 4.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  4.00000000e-01 0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01 0.00000000e+00 -4.00000000e-01  2.00000000e-01  2.00000000e-01 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.10000000e+01]
 [ 1.10000000e+01  6.93889390e-18  0.00000000e+00  1.33333333e-01 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e-01 6.66666667e-02 -1.33333333e-01  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  8.76666667e+01]
 [ 1.20000000e+01  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  4.00000000e-01 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 -4.00000000e-01 -6.00000000e-01 -6.00000000e-01 0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  1.60000000e+01]]
```

my question is, how can I print this matrix in the following format (represent the simplex table)?

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a perfect solution and certainly a bit of a mess to maintain, here is an approach that gets close to what you are looking for. Note: Being lazy , I only formatted the first 4 columns and the last column, but this should give you an idea as to how to proceed with the others.

```
def format_array(ar):
    shp = ar.shape 
    for r in range(shp[0]):
        lst = ar[r]
        print(f'{lst[0]:>6.0f} | {lst[1]:>12.6g} |  {lst[3]:>12.6g} | {lst[4]:>12.6g} | {lst[5]:<12.6g} ||{lst[14]:<12.6g}')
        if r == 0:
            print('='.rjust(80,'='))
```

Given your array, this is the result of the above:

```
    -1 |            0 |       2.13333 |            0 | 0            ||2427.67     
================================================================================
     3 |            0 |             0 |            1 | 0            ||400         
     1 |            0 |            -8 |            0 | 0            ||80          
     5 |            0 |     -0.533333 |            0 | 0            ||1.33333     
     0 |            1 |             4 |            0 | 0            ||160         
     4 |            0 |           0.4 |            0 | 1            ||11          
    11 |  6.93889e-18 |      0.133333 |            0 | 0            ||87.6667     
    12 |            0 |           0.4 |            0 | 0            ||16
```

​